# Is there a software that can make Wireframes from given url or jpg

Tags: url, wireframe

Is it possible ?

Or I just imagine ?

Comment: What do you mean a Wireframe? As in [skeletonization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it will convert images or URLs, but I know that http://www.axure.com/ comes recommended.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for tool to creating wireframe, ForeUI is worth trying out.